# Migration from Vue 1 to Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I migrate the Coerce option? I have read the Vue docs but I can't get it to work. What is it that I am doing not correct?

```
props: {
    date : {
        type: Number,
        coerce: str => Math.trunc(Date.parse(str) / 1000)
    },
},
```

Comment: ["If you want to coerce a prop, setup a local computed value based on it instead"](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#coerce-Prop-Option-removed) - have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Kos said, you have to use a computed property instead:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#coerce-Prop-Option-removed